# create bar chart with D3

Tags: d3.js

Hi everyone I am starting with D3.JS, and I want to show a bar with the temperature of a place.

This is my code

```
json_url= "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/7edu-s3u7.json";
var all_name_station = ["63rd Street Weather Station", "Foster Weather Station", "Oak Street Weather Station"];
var one_name_station = ["63rd Street Weather Station"];

var width = 900;
var height = 400;

$(document).ready(function(){
    d3.json(json_url, function(data) {
    var canvas = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);


     one_name_station.forEach(function(station_item){
                data.forEach(function(item_data){
          if (item_data["station_name"] == station_item){
                //console.log(item_data);
            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(item_data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                  .attr("width", function(d) {return d.air_temperature;})
                  .attr("height", 50)
                  .attr("y", function(d,i){return d;})
                  .attr("fill", "blue");
           }
        });
     });
    });
 });
```

I take my data from JSON, there are many station but I start only represente the data for `"63rd Street Weather Station"`

But my problems is that this code don't return nothing. You can try [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/maitep/z2k92g8o/)

What I missing!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that right now you are not passing an iterable to `data`, just an object. If you wrap `item_data` in an array it will create a single blue rectangle:

```
.data([item_data])
```

Then you will have other problems, however, such as setting `y`. I would recommend reformatting your data first into a list of objects (instead of appending them one at a time), and building off of [one of the canonical bar chart examples](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

Comment: Thanks @mdml, but what happens with the other  bar why show only one!

Comment: @Stone: you need to change how you compute y. I'm not sure what you had intended, so perhaps you can clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass array of data, not by one item. So, compile the array of proper stations first, and then pass it to d3:

```
//array of objects
var stations = [{name: "Station 1", air_temperature: 19.5},
                            {name: "Station 2", air_temperature: 21.5},
                            {name: "Station 3", air_temperature: 20},];
//adding bars
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                 .data(stations)
                 .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d) {return d}) //guess: pass through function figuring out the right scale
                    .attr("height", 50) //guess: pass through function figuring out the right scale
                    .attr("y", function(d,i){return d.air_temperature;}) //guess: multiply by scaleFactor, obtained depending on number of entries in data and canvas size
                    .attr("fill", "blue"); //guess: pass through d3.scale.linear() function
```

Comment: Thanks @Vadim I am very new with D3, my JSON is like your station array `https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/7edu-s3u7.json`  but what happen if I only want to show station1 and station3

Comment: Me too). Refine the array stations before putting it in d3 `data` like this: `var proper_list = function(all_stations, array_of_required_stations){
 return all_stations.filter(s => s.name in array_of_required_stations)
};`